# Microsoft Chart Control Axis Titles not displaying properly

Tags: c#, gridview, charts

I am having problems getting the XAxis to display the correct values in my chart control.  Below is how I am generating each series to be displayed.  I would like the XAxis to display the DataType value from s.DataType:

```
 foreach (SummaryData s in summaryData)
    {
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series(s.DataType);
        series.ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;            
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();            
        dp.Name = s.DataType;            
        dp.SetValueY(s.Total);
        dp.SetCustomProperty("DataType", s.DataType);
        series.XValueMember = "DataType";                        
        series.Points.Add(dp);
        msBarVertLegRight.Series.Add(series);            
    }
    msBarVertLegRight.DataBind();
```

The corect value is displayed and the correct name in the Legend, but I'm not exactly sure how to set the XAxis value.

JH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use databinding (which is what the `XValueMember` is for) and add points one by one. You can do one or the other. You could use databinding like so (approximately):

```
series.XValueMember = "DataType";
series.YValueMember = "ThePropertyWithY";
series.DataSource = s;
series.DataBind();
```

or you could set each point individually:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("mySeries");
series.ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

foreach (SummaryData s in summaryData)
{                
    series.AddXY(s.DataType, s.Total);
}
```

I'm not sure why you had each `SummaryData.DataType` being its own series; if that is needed, add that back in, but from the code you posted it didn't seem necessary.

When databinding, any changes to your underlying data (the `SummaryData` objects) will be reflected in your chart automatically; if you add points individually, you need to handle updates to your chart manually.

Comment: This helped the Axis, it is now correctly displayed on the bottom but now my legend only shows the one series and there is only one color on the chart.  I would like each data point represented with it's own color and represented in the legend as well.

Comment: Then create a new series for each `SummaryData` object. Just move the first two lines into the `foreach` loop, and make sure to call `chart.Series.Add(series)` at the end of the loop.